# Wicket: resource url mapping (file system)

Tags: url, resources, mapping, wicket

I have an Wicket application with Tomcat and Spring. Inside the application there is an audio playback node.
Audio files are stored in the file system outside of application folder. When user asks to play a file, Tomcat has a configuration to map an url and retrieve the file from folder in the file system.

I want to move this mapping to the Wicket side, but I still want to store files in file system(there are really lots of it) and i want it to have secured url(not to show my file system structure). How can I implement this mapping in the way?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/) blog post then implement custom Resource class, check sources of DynamicImageResource